# Ninjas in a Chat Log

Tags: code-golf, string, text-processing

*Thanks to [HyperNeutrino](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/68942/hyperneutrino) for making more test cases*

Often in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/240/the-nineteenth-byte), someone will ask a question, and multiple people will answer it at the same time. Usually, the person who was beaten to the gun will say "ninja'd", creating even more unnecessary chat.

Given a chat log similar to the following:

```
Community: Hi
Test: Hi
Rando: What is 4 times 4?
Test: @Rando 16
Community: @Rando 16
Community: ninja'd
```

You are looking for the number of extraneous lines, which in the above exchange is 2. Two users both replied to another user with the same text, although he only wanted one answer, and then the second user said "ninja'd".

## Extraneous Messages

Note that for the following statement, a message is only the content left of the `:<space>`. However, if an extraneous message is removed, the `<username>:<space>` is also removed.

Your only task is finding extraneous messages in the input, and counting them. The first type of extraneous message is a message **starting with `@`** that is basically (spaces and case differences are ignored) the same as the message before it. The second type of extraneous message is a message reading exactly `ninja'd` (case insensitive) immediately after an extraneous message of the first type **by the same user** (there will never be users with the same name in different cases, and the same user will always be in the same case).

## Input

Your input is the chat log, including the user's names, followed by a colon and a space, followed by their message. You may take the input as a newline-separated string, a list of strings, or another appropriate input format.

## Output

Your output is the number of extraneous messages.

## Test Cases

```
Community: Hi
Test: Hi
Rando: What is 4 times 4?
Test: @Rando 16
Community: @Rando 16
Community: NINJA'D

2
```

```
A: how is everyone doing today
B: good
C: good
C: this doesn't work: `print5`
A: @C add a space
B: @C add aSpace
B: ninja'd
C: ninja'd

2
```

```
A: test
B: @A hi
C: @Ahi
C: ninja'd

2
```

```
A: test
B: @A hi
B: @A hi
B: ninja'd

2
```

```
A: 
B: @
B: @
B: ninja'd
B: ninja'd

2
```

```
A: ninja'd
B: ninja'd
C: @B ninja'd
B: @B ninja'd
B: ninja'd
C: ninja'd
C: ninja'd

2
```

```
Test: test
Testie: @Test TESTIE
Test: @Testie TESTIE
Test: ninja'd
Testie: TESTIE
Test: TESTIE

0
```

```
A: @B hi
C: @B hi
C: ninja'd
B: @C no
A: @CNO
A: ninja'd

4
```

Comment: [Sandbox](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/13205/65836)

Comment: @programmer5000 ninja'd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 50 bytes

```
T`l`L
 

(:@.*)¶(.+)\1
b$2a
b(.*)a¶\1:NINJA'D
aa
a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/P8/JCEnwYdLgYtLw8pBT0vz0DYNPW3NGEOuJBWjRK4kDaBQ4qFtMYZWfp5@Xo7qLlyJiVxAXY5WCg5OChmZXM5IjLzMvKxE9RQuJ6CYs0JePhdIlbOfP4iGygEA)

Comment: This is the answer to life, the universe, and everything ... +1

Comment: @Zacharý Not anymore :(

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 237 bytes

```python
l=lambda s:s[1].lower().replace(' ','')
m=[x.split(': ')for x in input()]
i=[0]
for j in range(1,len(m)):i+=[[m[j][1].lower()=="ninja'd"and i[-1]>1and m[j-1][0]==m[j][0],2][l(m[j-1])==l(m[j])and'@'==m[j][1][0]]]
c=i.count
print c(1)+c(2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZBRb4MgFIXf/RU3vgCpM9VkLyY03foT9khIyoQpDsEgnfXXO7Qza3IfvntyziHcYQ6ts@WyGGpE/ykFjNXICp4bNymPSe7VYEStMAKUIUSSnrJ7Pg5GB4wqQOTLebiDtnGGW8CEJ5qyI09WvVt1L2yjcJEZZXFPSKUPlLGedfzpFUpTq20nkEyFlaDZS8FPxYrRGDkWUrpljjwrOTP4ocfghpxELzqjP9MW4Dypqc5rd7MhGby2AWpckEONS7IsLH2roHUT6BHUj/Kzswqk07aB4KSY0yx9r6BxTka6PFNoY0Q6NVoUYHL@u4LrVv96jYbYer6AkBLiJYd4uEfRrn38S/uHt9J94b8)

-19 bytes thanks to Zacharý

Comment: @totallyhuman No >.< I solved it after I came back from playing outside with my brother lol.

Comment: Dude. Ýou really need to learn to remove useless spaces: `1 and`=>`1and`. (Put the ý in if ýou credit, please).

Comment: Change the final line into these two: `c=i.count` and `print c(1)+c(2)`.

Comment: @Zacharý ok, thanks. will make those edits

Comment: Can you combine the for loop into this: `for j in range(1,len(m)):i+=[2]if'@'==m[j][1][0]and l(m[j-1][1])==l(m[j][1])else[m[j][1].lower()=="ninja'd"and i[-1]>1and m[j-1][0]==m[j][0]]`?

Comment: @Zacharý yes, that works. thanks.

Comment: Oh, make it `i+=[2if'@'==m[j][1][0]and l(m[j-1][1])==l(m[j][1])else m[j][1].lower()=="ninja'd"and i[-1]>1and m[j-1][0]==m[j][0]]`

Comment: Make it `i+=[[m[j][1].lower()=="ninja'd"and i[-1]>1and m[j-1][0]==m[j][0],2][l(m[j-1][1])==l(m[j][1])and'@'==m[j][1][0]]]` instead

Comment: @ovs thanks but Zacharý got a shorter one :)

Comment: @Zacharý y u troll me with weird spaces :( lol

Comment: What do you mean? I honestly have no idea what you are talking about.

Comment: Also, you can save a few 3 bytes by changing including the `[1]` in the definition of `l` and changing the calls to `l` accordingly.

Comment: @Zacharý 1. Never mind, I forgot that comments do weird things with spaces to force wrapping; ignore my comment. Also, thanks for the other golf.

Comment: Make the `l` definition `l=lambda s:m[s][1].lower().replace(' ','')` and then change the calls to `l` accordingly again.

Comment: Oh, I just realized something: python2 uses `raw_input` for strings ...

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 122 bytes

```python
lambda s:sub(r"b(.*)a\n\1:NINJA'D",'aa',sub(r'.+(:@.*)\n(.+)\1',r'b\2a',sub(' ','',s.upper()))).count('a')
from re import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TYy9DoMgFIV3noK4XFRCYruZNPGnSzvYF2DBqpGmAgEcfHqKrUPvck7O9@Wazc9ancN04eEtln4Q2JVu7YlNesKyVHDFi7K7dfcargkFIYB@MbCclFU0uCIsT3kB1ELPTwcHDBRiZasxoyVpPPbUq/IEBKRosnrBdsRyMdr6LPwSu80hY2W0JhI7c36QitlRDPuHUJe4avAsUftXlFQvAQNq4tZipdFutd1jz4N9AA)

Port of my Retina answer